# How can I get the value of a data-attribute in an Alpine.js component?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am trying to get the `data-countdown` value (date and time) from my component into `x-data`, so that I can create a countdown timer out of it.

I went through the documentation and couldn't find anything which could help me get the value. I use `x-model` to the value of input, but as this won't be changing, I just need the access to the value.

I tried it with `x-bind` with no luck.

This is a blade file. I am using this in roots-sage.

```
<div class='countdown' x-bind:data-countdown="{ 'time': {{ $class[time][day] }} {{ $class[time][time] }} }">
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript code.

```
window.singleGroupClass = function () {
  return {
    data: 'hey',
    time: console.log(this.el),
    countdown() {
      console.log(this);
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you would implement the whole thing with Alpine.js might be something like the following.

Note that you need quotes around `{{ $class[time][day] }} {{ $class[time][time] }}`).

```html
<div class='countdown' x-data="singleGroupClass({ 'time': '{{ $class[time][day] }} {{ $class[time][time] }}' })">
</div>
<script>
  window.singleGroupClass = function (seedData) {
    return {
      time: seedData.time,
      countdown() {
        console.log(this);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely need to use the value in `data-countdown` attribute:

```html
<div class='countdown' x-data="{ time : $el.dataset.countdown }" data-countdown="{{ $class[time][day] }} {{ $class[time][time] }}">
  <div x-text="time"></div>
</div>
```

Note that it'll be difficult to do `data-countdown="{ 'time': '{{ $class[time][day] }} {{ $class[time][time] }}' }"` since you'll need to parse it as JSON (potentially).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I just need to access the value. I was okay to drop the data-countdown attribute. Thank a lot!

Comment: Hey @Hugo, although this works, but it also throws an error :  `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Function (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Hey, I solved it. It was some other code in the same component throwing the error.

Comment: Note: If you created a data attribute with spine case format, it will automatically be converted to camel case. Example: to grab `data-js-selector=123` you should use: `$el.dataset.jsSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

try, in Html

```
<div x-data="alpineComponent()" id="reviews" data-reviews='<?= $dataObj ?>'></div>
```

in Js

```
{
  return {
    reviews: JSON.parse(document.getElementById('reviews').dataset.reviews)
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.